# how to send a closure with captures through the mpsc channel in rust?

Tags: rust, closures, channel

I would like to implement an executor that can execute the packaged tasks in queue. Firstly, I
hope to make different types of functions into one type using a closure, and send the closure into a channel, then receive and execute it in another thread. The codes are below :

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;
macro_rules! packed_task {    
    ($f:ident, $($arg:expr),*) => {move ||{
        $f($($arg,)*)
    }};
}
macro_rules! packed_method_task {
    ($f:ident,$ins:ident, $($arg:expr),*) => {move ||{
        $ins.$f($($arg,)*);
    }};
    ($f:ident,$ins:ident $($arg:expr),*) => {move ||{
         $ins.$f($($arg,)*);
    }};
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> u32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
    fn area1(&self, w:u32, h:u32) -> u32 {
        w*h
    }
}
fn invoke_1(a:i32, b:i32, c:i32)->i32{
    let fc = |x,y,z| x+y+z + 1;
    return packed_task!(fc, a, b,c)();
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", invoke_1(1,2,3));
    let rect1 = Rectangle { width: 30, height: 50 };
    let b = packed_method_task!(area1, rect1, 60, 90);
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    
    let handle= thread::spawn(move || {
        let _received = rx.recv().unwrap();
        _received();
    });
    
    tx.send(b).unwrap();
    handle.join();
}
```

But I compile with errors:

```
|     let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
   |         -------- consider giving this pattern the explicit type `(Sender<T>, std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<T>)`, with the type parameters 
specified
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: "*I can't compile it successfully*"—why not?  Error messages convey reasons, from which solutions can be derived.  Rust's error messages are some of the clearest, most informative and helpful that I've ever seen.  Include them in your question.

Comment: The main  reason is that I don't know how to use the type of a closure with captures, because it has a different type with different captures! If a closure without captures, I can use fn() to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every closure is its own type, and Rust does not (currently) have any syntax with which to annotate such types.  Even if it did, creating a channel for such a closure would be a little pointless, as only that one closure could ever be sent through the channel.

Instead, send [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html):

```rust
let b = Box::new(packed_method_task!(area1, rect1, 60, 90));
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Box<dyn Send + Fn()>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5e4fdedb99527fdc8bda3ed74fdbda9d).